# Automatic location of new excel file generated from python script and send out emails

Tags: python, automation

I apologise for my over-simplification of the problem. May I ask does anyone know the feasible workflow (in Python) of how can the Window PC automatically locate new excel file generated from python script and send out emails daily? Thanks.

Comment: You generate your excel file in the same directory from python? If the same directory you wont have any big issue accessing that file and send out email. For email you may refer to this if you are using gmail https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Yes, I generate my excel file in the same directory from python. I have looked into the link you provided but I am still confused. Does this link teach how to send the email to others without manually attach the excel file into the email?

Comment: Yes you can refer to send email example (create_message_with_attachment)  or refer to this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python